# What is the difference between the adversary and the algorithm?

Tags: provable-security

I recently saw a sketch relating to provable security in a book, regarding the amount of time it takes to factor N where N = pq and p,q are primes.

It says that "There is a trivial algorithm which always factors a number in time $\sqrt N$ , so there is an adversary $A$ such that $Adv_b (A, 2^{b/2}) = 1$" b is the amount of bits of $N$.

Here there is a distinction drawn between the adversary and the algorithm. However, if the algorithm can always factor a number in $\sqrt N$ why does it matter, how strong the adversary is?

Comment: An adversary is someone who wields an algorithm.  Usually adversaries are limited in computational budget.  But if the book draws a distinction other than that, it would be helpful for you to quote _what_ distinction the book claims to draw if it's not clear; otherwise we're left guessing what the author of the book might have been thinking about while writing text we can't see.

Comment: "An adversary is someone who wields an algorithm." I have seen places where the adversary is assumed to be bounded computationally. If the adversary has an algorithm that can solve the problem in constant time. Why does it matter that he is computationally bounded?

Comment: Not all algorithms will run within the adversary's budget.  There's an _algorithm_ which finds a ChaCha key given a ChaCha ciphertext by trying all $2^{256}$ possible keys, but there's no _adversary_ who can afford to run that algorithm to completion.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Makes sense. If an algorithm does run within the adversaries budget, can I assume that the running time of the algorithm and the running time of the adversary are equal?

Comment: You can use the words that way if you like, using ‘adversary’ to mean ‘cost-limited algorithm’, but it's impossible to say what the source you're _reading_ means by it if you don't quote it.  This question is unanswerable without reference to your source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is just stating that *since* there exists an algorithm that can factor a number in time sqrt(N), we can use what we know about this algorithm to calculate the probability that the adversary can win an indistinguishability game against a challenger using this encryption scheme.

In other words, the algorithm is used to calculate the advantage of the adversary. Since the algorithm can factor $N$ in time sqrt(N), we must pick big enough primes, so that no probabilistic polynomial time adversary can attack the system.

Comment: Does this only make sense, if the adversary is limited by resources?

Comment: Yes, but we usually assume the adversary **is** limited by the resources available from modern day computers. This is the difference between computational security and information-theoretic security. The former allows for a small possibility of failure and takes into consideration computational limits. The latter requires a secure encryption scheme against an adversary with **unlimited computational power**. Because informational-theoretic security is so hard to accomplish. computational security is usually used.

Comment: When you say advantage, do you mean the probability that the adversary wins?

Comment: Almost. An adversary's advantage in an indistinguishability game (which is often used to prove security) is the probability above 1/2 that the adversary will win the game. In indistinguishability games, the adversary gets to choose two messages, and then guess which message was encrypted, They will always have at least 50% chance of winning (just by guessing randomly). The probability that the Adversary wins the game is 1/2 + Advantage

Comment: Is there a probability that once you go over, the system is insecure? Also where can I find information on all of these games? My resources have been pretty scattered

Comment: Introduction To Modern Cryptography by Yehuda Lindell and Jonathan Katz is a superb resource. Chapters 2 and 3 will explain the games. Here is a link to the free PDF: https://repo.zenk-security.com/Cryptographie%20.%20Algorithmes%20.%20Steganographie/Introduction%20to%20Modern%20Cryptography.pdf . You can also buy a used edition of version 2 for pretty cheap

Comment: In order to prove that a scheme is secure, you have to prove that the Adversary has negligible advantage over 1/2. If you cannot prove this, and the adversary's advantage is always above 1/2, then the scheme is definitely insecure.

Comment: :) Happy to help

Comment: What does an advantage of $1^n * b$ mean?  What notion of advantage are you talking about?  If we pick primes of any _particular_ size, then there's a PPT algorithm to factor them, indeed an algorithm running in $O(1)$ time.

Comment: I was just repeating what the OP posted. The general confusion was about what it means to talk about the advantage of an adversary. I’m guessing the context is an indistinguishability game. The text the OP was reading seems to be discussing the advantage of the adversary in relation to the trivial factoring algorithm

Comment: The text of the question includes ‘…$\mathit{Adv}_b(A, 2^{b/2}) = 1$ " b’ which is the only part that _resembles_ $1^n * b$, if you read " as superscript $n$ and juxtaposition as multiplication.  Am I missing something?  Do you (or OP) mean something by $1^n * b$?

Comment: Oh, I misread the quotation mark as n. I'll change it

Comment: The quotation mark was just the end of a quotation.  I don't think it or $b$ was intended to figure into any formula; if it did, it has no meaning with which I am familiar.  Can you phrase what you are trying to say with this notation, using different words, without just copying what was in the question verbatim?

Comment: This aspect of my answer is irrelevant to the answer itself. The point of the answer and question is to explain how we can use hard problems and known algorithms that solve those problems to calculate what the probability is that an adversary will win an indistinguishability game against a challenger working with a particular encryption scheme. That being said, I will change it

Comment: What does ‘the algorithm is used to calculate the advantage of the adversary’ mean?  Which algorithm?  How can one _use_ an algorithm to factor a large prime in order to _calculate_ the advantage of an adversary?  What is the distinction you're drawing between algorithm and adversary?

Comment: Well, an Adversary *is* an algorithm. Or you could look at it as an adversary is a malicious person who is using an algorithm to break an encryption scheme. If you view an adversary as someone playing an indistinguishability game, they will use an algorithm to figure out which of two cipher texts were encrypted. Using that algorithm, they will have a certain probability of guessing correctly. See Chapter 2 and 3 of Introduction to Modern Cryptography by Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell

Comment: I agree with Squeamish here, you are using two times "the algorithm" to refer to two different functions: the factoring itself and the one that can be used to calculate the advantage. That's terribly confusing. Furthermore, the adversary certainly is not an algorithm. It is a (virtual) entity that wants to break the system, e.g. by *using* a specific algorithm or set of algorithms. Or whatever means that are allowed within the defined "game".

Comment: Hm..in modern cryptography, adversaries are considered algorithms.  They are often referred to as "PPT adversaries", meaning probabilistic polynomial time algorithms designed to attack the system. Remember that an algorithm is just a set of steps to be followed in order to solve a problem. In modern cryptography, to prove a system is secure you prove that no algorithm can break the given system. The OP's question is asking about an explanation in some text book that is using the methodology of modern cryptography. Also, In my actual answer, I use "algorithm" only to refer to the factoring

Comment: algorithm and I state that we can use this algorithm to calculate the advantage of the adversary. So I don't really see what is confusing about that. If you are referring to my comments as the source of confusion, that was an attempt to answer a barrage of questions that are not directly related to the actual question being answered. In any case, everything I'm stating is inline with the theory behind indistinguishability games, which again you can read in Chapter 2 and 3 of Introduction to Modern Cryptography

Comment: https://repo.zenk-security.com/Cryptographie%20.%20Algorithmes%20.%20Steganographie/Introduction%20to%20Modern%20Cryptography.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> However, if the algorithm can always factor a number in $\sqrt N$ why does it matter, how strong the adversary is?

In this particular case the statements made are:

- If we can deterministically factor, we can deterministically break RSA.
- If we can factor in time $\sqrt N$ then our adversary also runs in time $2^{b/2}\approx \sqrt N$.

While these may be somewhat obvious in this case, for different algorithms the factoring may be probabilistic and then there would be a relation of the impact of this probability on the advantage. In general this notation was probably used for the purpose of consistency.